# Migrate git rep from GCP to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, repository, aws-codecommit

We have repositories in "Google Cloud Platform".Now I want to move GCP  repo's to "AWS " .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is a two step process where you clone the repo from the Git Server to your local computer and then push to CodeCommit.

Following document has the details on the steps involved:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-migrate-repository-existing.html